# Synchronized method is not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class TestCases implements Serializable{

public TestCases() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Santhosh me = new Santhosh();
    MyThread myT1 = new MyThread(me);
    MyThread myT2 = new MyThread(me);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(myT1);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(myT2);

    t1.setName("one");
    t2.setName("two");

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

   }
 }
```

This is class whose object would be accessed by two threads

```
public class Santhosh {

private String name=null;

public void setName(String name){
    synchronized(this){
    System.out.println("changing name by "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    this.name = name;
    }
  }
}
```

My Thread class

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable{

private Santhosh santhu;

public MyThread(Santhosh me){
    this.santhu = me;
}

public void run(){
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
        this.santhu.setName(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
  }

}
```

I was expecting result to be like:

```
changing name by one
changing name by one
changing name by one
.
.
.
(1000 times)

changing name by two
changing name by two
.
.
.
(1000 times)
```

I know sequence could be different i.e.. 'Changing name by two' could come first (1000 times) and then 'Changing name by one' (1000 times)

But when I run this code I see something like this:

```
changing name by one
changing name by one
changing name by two
changing name by two
changing name by two
changing name by two
changing name by two
changing name by two
changing name by two
changing name by two
changing name by two
changing name by two
changing name by two
changing name by one --- ONE here
changing name by two
```

Comment: i think its a bit misunderstanding regarding synchronization.. if my memory serves me right, you ought never to make assumption on the sequence of concurrent thread execution -- its all up to the compiler and processor.

Comment: Why would you create threads to produce this kind of output? Just to test things? Still, the `synchronized` block is working as intended.

Comment: *Any* execution order is correct. There is no problem here.

Comment: In addition to the obvious misunderstanding in your expectations, the example is very artificial. It may help you to think of a realistic situation; you should especially think what you are going to *do* with the value you wrote. (In fact, the field writes would be atomic even without synchronized here, but even that doesn't matter because there is nobody observing any lack of atomicity.)

Comment: Also, it's worth pointing out that synchronized is not only needed for mutual exclusion but also visibility: a write by one thread is not necessarily visible to another thread without synchronized, even if there is no race condition.

Comment: @Sanz its because your thread enters the synchronized block, executes it and leaves it in each iteration leaving the opportunity for second thread to aquire the lock and enter the synchronized block. I have put this and little more in my answer which I hope will be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/43557121/504133

Answer (score 2):

In your case a `thread` on entering the `synchronized` block, executes it and leaves it in each iteration. Once a `Thread` leaves the `synchronized` block it leaves an opportunity for another competiting `thread` to aquire `lock` and enter the `synchronized` block.

For the result you expect you may modify the class `MyThread`'s `run()` method as below.

```
public void run(){
    synchronized(me){
          for(int i=0;i<1000;i++){
            this.santhu.setName(Thread.currentThread().getName());
          }
    }
  }
```

Also if you follow above way then you can remove the `synchronized` from `Santhosh` class `setName()` method.

P.S. Though you should keep proper contextual names but I understand here its just for the purpose of study but still  I would suggest to rename the class `MyThread` to `MyRunnable` as its an implementation of `Runnable` interface and its not a `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

Threads execute in whatever order the compiler and the processor decide. This includes a mixed order, with ones between twos and twos between ones. They don't wait for other threads to finish before executing. When using threads, you should expect them running at the same time. This is how they're supposed to behave: executing at the same time (alternating if single-core processor, concurrently if multi-core processor). There isn't anything wrong here. `synchronized` is working correctly: it prevents the threads from modifying the string at the same time (that's all it's supposed to do). Any execution order is correct.